# Replace multiple characters from a data string at once in Code by Zapier

Tags: javascript, python, replace

I want to replace multiple characters from my phone number data string.

Input data is this

```
+1 305-267-2700,+1 305-762-3890,+1 786-728-3885,+1 305-567-9589,+1 786-619-7070,+1 786-316-3187,
```

In some cases, there is + before the number and in some cases, there is space or -, so I want to remove them or replace them with nothing.

These are the characters I want to remove
“+”
“-”
“Space”

Zapier allows me to use javascript or python, what code can I use in there to replace these characters?

This is how the page where we enter the code in Zapier looks for reference, am new to this so not sure how all these work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV9Na.png)

Comment: Have a closer look at how to use `string.replace` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python**
Use `str.replace` to replace the character you want to remove with an empty string `''`

```
string = "+1 305-267-2700,+1 305-762-3890,+1 786-728-3885,+1 305-567-9589,+1 786-619-7070,+1 786-316-3187"

string = string.replace("+", "").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "")
```

**JavaScript**

```
string = "+1 305-267-2700,+1 305-762-3890,+1 786-728-3885,+1 305-567-9589,+1 786-619-7070,+1 786-316-3187"

string = string.replaceAll("+", "").replaceAll("-", "").replaceAll(" ", "")
```